Dynkin System - Ren L. Schilling - Measures, Integrals and Martingales.
I have a question regarding one of the lemmas (5.4) from the Book mentioned above.
A Dynkin system $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if, and only if, it is stable under finite intersections: $D1, D2 \in D \implies D1 \cap D2 \in D $. And to prove this it then says: Since a σ-algebra is ∩-stable (see Properties 3.2 and Problem 3.1) as well as a Dynkin system (Remark 5.2) it remains only to show that a ∩-stable
Dynkin system D is a σ-algebra.
So a Dynkin system is always stable under finite intersections?

No, you are reading it wrongly. They are saying that a $\sigma-$ algebra is closed under finite intersections and a $\sigma-$ algebra is also a Dynkin system.
